# json key start with asterisk

Tags: php, json, bigcommerce

I have print all my products in a json array. Everything looks good and working except that each key as an asterik in front of it (see pic)

[image]

Does anybody have already seen this? 
Look like i cannot access to the value and i guess is because of the asterisk.

Let's say i want to access my product id, what i tried is:

`product.id  // undefined`

`product["id"] //undefined`

`product["*id"] //undefined`

As you can see my product id is not empty so i'm pretty sure is not undefined.

I'm wondering if is some kind of way BigCommerce API use to communicate me that those keys are not available for me to use?
Maybe are just reference?

I'm thinking in this way because we create the same array for Categories and for Brands but we don't get the asterisk. 
Instead i see the same asterisk to the key `*commerceAPI`
[image]

Comment: Did you try `$product->id` ?

Comment: Execute `Object.keys(product)` and see what the keys are.

Comment: @KarolGasienica i should have explain my self better, sorry. In Php i create a json array of products but then i access it with js. So afaik i cannot access as $produc -> id in javascript

Comment: You should add #javascript tag then :)

Comment: @KarolGasienica maybe i should :)  i put php just because in my opinion the problem is coming from how the json array is created, which is done in php. 
But yeah maybe is js problem?

Comment: @karliwson keys are the one that are shown in the first pic: *fieldMap, *fields, ...